# How to change the alignment of the background image for small screen (tablet/smartphone etc.)

Tags: images

I'm using the standard WordPress "Twenty Seventeen" theme and have changed the default background image to a custom one.  The most important part of that image is the left margin.  I was unable to figure out how to make the image "left-aligned" so to speak, i.e., to make sure that when the browser window is resized or when viewing the content on a tablet and smartphone, that the right part of the window is cropped.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try

```
Background-size : Cover; 
Background-position:left center;
```

property in **Media** CSS after browser size **< 767**

Comment: Hmm, where would I find "Media CSS"? I do see a section "Additional CSS" in the sidebar, however, when I paste your code there it gives an error message.

Comment: You can add css in bottom of your style.css like below 

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.your_class/id {
    background-size : Cover; 
background-position:left center;
}